# How can i derive specific data from the string?

Tags: java, android, string, pattern-matching, arrays

I have the following string and i want to derive the number (**104321**) from the a href tag . How can i derive this number .

```
Hello this is testing string <a href=\"/testing/104321\">Ap</a><img src=\"Image Url" width=\"222\" height=\"149\"/><br/><br/>test\u00e4n p\u00e4\u00e4ll\u00e4 test, test\u00e4, test?
```

i want the final output to be like this.

```
String[] strExample= {"testing", "104321","test\u00e4n p\u00e4\u00e4ll\u00e4 test, test\u00e4, test?"};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a simple Pattern matcher with the regexp:

```
String THE_PATTERN = "<a\\s+href\\s*=\\s*\"/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(THE_PATTERN).matcher(THE_INPUT_STRING);
String[] results = new String[2];
if (m.find()) {
    results[0] = m.group(1);
    results[1] = m.group(2);
}
```

Haven't tried it though, so there could be small/easy-to-fix errors.

Comment: Ok, but you changed your question since I answered (you aded a third string to match). Just adapt the regexp, put parenthesis around the third part you want to match and m.group(3) will return it. Look into the `Pattern` javadoc for more info on regexp and `Matcher`

Comment: Thank you very . can you again help me ? i also want the string after <br/> tag . I also change my question . Please look at this and give me the solution . I am always thankful to you .

Comment: i never use the Pattern and Matcher before, so can you please help me to sort out my problem again ?

Comment: Yes but I don't know the variables. What is likely to change and what is supposed to be fixed?

Comment: i need the message after the image tag close and after the <br/> tag.

Comment: Then I would simply keep the answer above to match the two first strings. For the last one, I would use something like `inputString.substring(inputString.lastIndexOf("<br/>")+"<br/>".length());`

Comment: is it possible using the Pattern and Match ? Can you give the solution using that ?

Comment: Yes it is but it will not be efficient at all or it will be a very complex regexp to write (and therefore maintain). You could try something like this: "<a\\s+href\\s*=\\s*\"/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+).*<br/>(.*)" and the result should be in m.group(3); You may have to use the following "<a\\s+href\\s*=\\s*\"/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+).*?<br/>(.*)" if the matcher does not work (I added a '?' after the first .* which is a relunctant qualifier).

Answer (score 0):

For that single case

```
String[] strExample = str.split("^.+?\\\"/|\\\\\">.+<br/>|/");
```

will work. It will break if the string you want to parse changes much though. Some more examples would probably be in place if there are more patterns you need to account for.